# Use vector artwork for iOS launch image in asset catalog?

Tags: ios, asset-catalog, launchimage

Is this possible?  It looks like I am going to need 9 different launch images, so replacing them all would be a bit of a chore.

Comment: Now we can use PDF vector image for launch screen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think you can't use vector artwork for ALL of your LaunchImages...
... but there's an approach which makes our lives easier: the new `LaunchScreen.xib`.

In File > New, you create a new Launch Screen in User Interface:
[image: Creating Launch Screen]

Now, you can set the new Launch Screen File in your project's target:
[image: Setting your new Launch Screen]

In this LaunchScreen.xib you can put your vector artwork, using AutoLayout for adapt your vector to all screen sizes.

Why I told that you can't use vector artwork for ALL sizes? Because it only works in iOS 8+. For iOS 7, I created the PNG image and I put this in LaunchImage asset catalog, in the old way.
[image: LaunchImage iOS 7]

**PS: I tested this approach only in simulator.**

Comment: It's been a year, but can you elaborate on how you did this or upload the project somewhere?  Did you load an SVG into a UIWebView in the LaunchScreen.xib?  Did you use vector PDFs in an UIImageView to generate compile-time PNGs?

Comment: 1) Import vector PDFs to project (how to do it: http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/)
2) Implement LaunchScreen.xib (named by Apple as "Launch File") for iOS8+. Drag and drop UIImageView for LaunchScreen.xib and simple set vector PDF in Image property
3) Older iOS (iOS 6.1 for iPod 4th and iPhone 3GS; iOS 7.1 for iPhone 4) you need design Launch Image .PNG in old way. Add a LaunchImage in your Image.xcassets and uncheck "iOS 8.0 and Later".

Comment: We can use PDF vector image for launch screen

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with XCode 6. This is a new feature added with the new release.

The [Session 441](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#411) from WWDC 2014 give you more information about this way :)

- Make a new image set
- Click on the blank image set
- Choose vector into attributes inspector. *Now you have a universal image !*
- Drag your vector into this universal slot ;)

Enjoy !

Comment: But is it a launch image?

Comment: It is not. No vector option for LaunchImage's (yet?).