# storyboard launchimage when supporting iOS7 & iOS8

Tags: ios, image, ios7, storyboard, launch

I'm creating an app that supports iOS8 and iOS7.
iOS8 supports to use Storyboards as launchimage... 
But this doesn't work for iOS7.
But if I'm using Launch Images from the image.xcassets the launch image isn't loaded any more!

Is it possible to use storyboard-launch images for iOS8 and launch image from the Assets for iOS7?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** 
As soon as I'm using both, iOS8 LaunchScreens is black!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **Device using iOS 7** you can do as usual, what we used to do using `images.xcassets`  [image]

For **iOS 8 devices** you have two ways..

1. Simply you can use `LaunchScreen.xib`. 
   [image] 
   this image show how Xcode by defaults sets `LaunchScreen.xib` for iOS 8 launch screen file.

   2. If you don't want to set `LaunchScreen.xib` as launch screen file and want to display some launch image as you want in iOS 7 device, so just remove launch screen file name and make it blank(see below image) and delete `LaunchScreen.xib` file from `Xcode`. In this case iOS 8 device also takes launch image from launch images from `images.xcassets`.
      [image]

Reference : [Suryakant Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26293983/3859370)

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a common problem, which happens when we build a new application with xCode 6.2 (and later), and set the deployment target to iOS 7. The lack of LaunchImage causes the app to run in 3.5-inch mode on iOS7 device.

If you specify both LaunchScreen and LaunchImages, the app runs fine on both iOS7 and iOS8.