# Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5, using launchscreen.xib for iOS 8 target

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, launch-screen

I have fully completed my application and am at the stage where I would like to submit my application to the appstore. After clicking the archive button and pressing the "submit to appstore" button, I receive the following error message:

Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 - - New iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5 and must include a launch image referenced in the Info.plist under UILaunchImages with a UILaunchImageSize value set to {320, 568}. Launch images must be PNG files and located at the top-level of your bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you localize your launch images. Learn more about iPhone 5 support and app launch images by reviewing the 'iOS Human Interface Guidelines' at 'https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5' and the 'iOS App Programming Guide' at 'https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12'.

I don't understand why I am getting this error message because I have set my deployment target for iOS 8 in which case I believe I can use the launchscreen.xib (which is what I am currently using). Some other information is that my application only runs in landscape mode (not sure if this is even relevant).

I am also not sure wether it would simply be better to use the LaunchImage under the image.xcassetes folder in order to resolve this problem. For me, this LaunchScreen image set only requires me to upload a 2X and retina 4 for iPhone portrait iOS 7,8

I really appreciate any help as I would like to ideally release my application as soon as possible.

Comment: please check my answer about setting launch screen for iOS app: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28185894/1280373

Comment: I am trying to do your method; however, when I go to the info.plist file and I click on the + and scroll through the options, there is no option for UILaunchImages. Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Comment: Use assets catalog that is easy n same thing as I explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says,

> Launch images must be PNG files

Therefore, you need to set it for iPhone 5 and all other devices your app is going to support.

Go to your image.xcassetes> LaunchImages. Open the right side pannel and set following: (I am assuming your target is iOS8 and greater and your app is in landscape version only). Retina HD 5.5's size should be : 2208 x 1242 pixels.

[image]

Comment: I tried doing what you said and uploaded a 2208 pixel by 1242 pixel image to the Retina HD 5.5 but when I try to submit it to the appstore I am getting the same error message, any ideas?

Comment: I think you should select iOS 8.0 and Later both Potrait and landscape mode, and iOS 7.0 and later, iPhone Potrait. And then set the splash screens, clean the build, archive and submit again. If this resolves the matter, do let me know