# Splash in ios app

Tags: ios, xcode, splash-screen, info.plist

I'm working on old project without constraints and this splash images.

```
Default-568h@2x.png                640 x 1136
Default.png                        320 x 480
Default@2x.png                     640 x 960
```

not have `Images.xcassets` catalog and not have configured this splash in `.plist` like [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967792/how-to-integrate-splash-screen-for-all-types-of-iphones-in-xcode-6-1#28185894).

All this causes me big impression, because I had never seen anything like it.

Investigating all that, I realized that i had to do anything to make it work, it is only necessary to have the `splash` with these specific names and it works throughout the application very well on all devices (including`ipad`).

***All excellent here. !!Looks good in all Devices!!!! ***

Now the big problem is that I need to have a different splash for each target. So *I based on the above mentioned post*, i try adding everything in the `Images.xcassets` or .`plist` (I tried 2 ways).

I even noticed some dimensions that made me more.

```
DefaultQA-568h.png                   320 x 568      
DefaultQA-568h@2x.png                640 x 1136
DefaultQA-667h@2x.png                750 x 1334
DefaultQA-736h@3x.png                1242 x 2208
DefaultQA.png                        320 x 480
DefaultQA@2x.png                     640 x 960
```

> I put another name because it did not want the original target that work well, are damaged

But the application on some devices looks very bad (iPhone 6 and iPad). But in the target which has not set the splash in `.plist` or `Images.xcassets`, still it works perfect.

**There any way to have 2 groups splash by default for each target, without having to configure them in the `.plist` or `Images.xcassets`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create different splash screens for different targets without changing `Images.xcassets` or `.plist` files.

You can even use the same file name as long as they are on different folders like so:

[image: File Structure]

Just select each splash screen image you want and make sure only the correct target can see that image. For example:

[image: Target 1]

[image: Target 2]

This way, the only asset the target will see is the one assigned to it.
This is how the `.plist` looks like:

[image: plis]

I've only did some changes to make sure no storyboard was being used to match the requirements you posted.